Suppose that y + x = 2y − x, and x and y are not both zero. Prove that y is not equal to 0.
My solution is suppose y is 0, given y+x=2y-x, it follows that 2x=y. Given y=0, it can be derived that X =0. The x and y values contradicts the given statement that x and y values are not both zero. Hence y is not equal to 0.
Is my prove correct? I'm fairly new to proving and do not mind feedback thanks!

Your proof is correct , you could also start with $x=-x$ (assuming $y=0$) , but the way you did it also works.

Correctness of a proof depends on the formal system in question. In your case, what are the properties of $+, -$, of $2y$, of $=$, that you have? For example, if these are remainders modulo $2$ and the operations are modulo $2$, then the proof is not correct, since the statement is not true in general $0 + 1 = 2\cdot 0-1\pmod{2}$.

Without context , everyone assumes that $x,y$ are real numbers. Anything else would have to be explicitely mentioned.

@Peter In mathematics, what is not said, is allowed. So, no, not everyone assumes that.

To check for correctness all you need to do is check if the individual steps that you did are allowed. For example, when you went from $y+x=2y-x$ to $2x=y$, supposedly you did things like adding $-y$ on both sides (and $x$ on both sides). The first would give $(y+x)+(-y)=(2y-x)+(-y)$. For this to actually cancel the $y$'s on the left you would need to be able to change $y+x$ with $x+y$ and $(x+y)+(-y)$ into $x+(y+(-y))$. If your $+$ is commutative and associative, then these are allowed and you are good. If not, then maybe not.

When you went from $2x=y$ and $y=0$ to $x=0$, you deduced from $2x=y=0$, that $2x=0$, and from this that $x=0$. In the first you used that $=$ is transitive. If your $=$ is transitive you are good. In the second you had to cancel the $2$. Are you allowed to cancel the $2$ in $2x=0$? If so, you are good. If not, and it is not always possible, then maybe not.

I've been a professional mathematician for a while now and I have never explicitly said what formal system I'm using, what + or - are, or that equality is transitive. Sometimes reading the room is more beneficial than confusing the audience.

When the addition of your variables is associative, then it it looks ok. But if you're dealing with a system where $(y+x)+x$ is not necessarily equal to $y+2x$, then you might have a problem.
